# doing system administration with a Makefile approach

Tags: system-administration

I would like to automatize some sysadmin tasks, such as:

- creating user accounts
- creating folders
- setting permissions
- copying config files
- maybe templating some files if they are too repetitive

I tested three approaches so far:

1. **bash scripts**: it works, but can be tricky sometimes (not used to the syntax)
2. **ansible**: I can make it work too, but it really feels overcomplicated for the things I want to do (also, I just HATE writing nested for loops in yaml)
3. **Makefile**: it is surprisingly convenient to define targets for the various files I want to create, but there are corner cases (such as handling multiline strings, skipping a target if a file is found and not testing permissions)

I searched for a tool that would fit the bill: simple system administration with a makefile approach, but could not find anything. Anyone know of a tool that could do that?